# How to decode Base64 text using Karate

Tags: karate

I am able to encode a plain text to Base64 in Karate but vice versa is throwing errors.

```
`def decode =
"""
function(password){
var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
byte[] decodedText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(password);
String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
return decodedString;
}
"""
def decodedVal = decode(dGVzdGluZw==)
print decodedVal

Error Message in the logs
-unknown-:9 - javascript evaluation failed: function(password){
var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
byte[] decodedText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(password);
String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
return decodedString;
}, :3:9 Expected an operand but found ]
byte[] decodedText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(password);
^ in at line number 3 at column number 9`
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change to this:

```
* def decodedVal = decode('dGVzdGluZw==')
```

But I see a lot of syntax errors and wrong usage. Suggest you go through the docs and examples, or take the help of someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and it will work to decode the string in karate

```
  * def decoded =
    """
    function decode(password) {
      var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
      var decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(password);
      var String = Java.type('java.lang.String');
      return new String(decoded);
    }
    """
```